# Alternative to death, brother to fraternity

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues

> Small taste post-Christ and an article, confused is panda. (7)
>   Charles' gateway monument messed up Chad's WinRAR. (11)
>   Unreaching paradox person and curious alpha backed out of a Thai bone zone. (7)
>   Big melancholic opening misinterpreted by Leo, a rebel thug. (13)
>   Alternative to death, brother to fraternity. (7)

What are we listing?

Comment: Acrostic: scuba

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are listing

> good places to go diving, as per the acrostic.

Solutions:

Small taste post-Christ and an article, confused is panda. (7)

> SIPADAN (sip + AD + an / ISPANDA*). Sipadan is a Malaysian island and one of the world's top diving destinations.

Charles' gateway monument messed up Chad's WinRAR. (11)

> DARWIN'S ARCH (Charles Darwin + the thing in St Louis / CHADSWINRAR*). This is a natural arch formation near Darwin Island in the Galapagos.

Unreaching paradox person and curious alpha backed out of a Thai bone zone. (7)

> ZENOBIA (Zeno + bi + a / thAIBONEZone<). The *Zenobia* was a Swedish ferry wrecked off Cyprus, now a popular place for diving.

Big melancholic opening misinterpreted by Leo, a rebel thug. (13)

> GREAT BLUE HOLE (great = big etc.; LEOAREBELTHUG*). The Great Blue Hole, in Belize, is just what the name implies.

Alternative to death, brother to fraternity. (7)

> LIBERTY ("give me liberty or give me death!" / "liberté, égalité, fraternité"). The USAT Liberty was wrecked in Bali and is a popular diving site.

Comment: Yup, this is exactly it. Nice work.